# Is the "qword" type specifier not allowed on characters or on certain variable sizes? (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I found the following code on a tutorial website and was trying to edit it to get a better grasp on assembly. I have not been able to find anything online explaining it.

```
section .text
   global _start     
_start:             
    
   mov  edx, 9       
   mov  ecx, foo   
   mov  ebx, 1       
   mov  eax, 4      
   int  0x80        
    
   mov  [foo], qword 'aaaaaaaa' 
    
   mov  edx, 8       
   mov  ecx, foo    
   mov  ebx, 1       
   mov  eax, 4       
   int  0x80        
    
   mov  eax, 1       
   int  0x80        

section .data
foo db 'abcdefgh', 0xa
```

The code above gives the following error due to the qword keyword and the string being 8 characters.

> test.asm:11: error: operation size not specified

Why is this not accepted?

Comment: 1. I think you  need to put the size specifier on the memory operand, not the immediate. At least that's how it is normally done. 2. There's no instruction with a memory destination and an 8-byte immediate operand.

Comment: By "There's no instruction with a memory destination and and an 8-byte immediate operand." do you mean that I cannot move 8 bytes of data into a memory location in one instruction?

Comment: You can if the data fits into a 32-bit signed immediate.

Comment: First of all, you're using 32-bit `int 0x80` system calls, so this should be assembled as 32-bit code, in which case qword operand-size isn't available for anything.  (Except cmpxchg8b, x87, and SSE/AVX.)

Comment: But if you assemble as 64-bit, then it's a duplicate of the linked dups at the top of the page.  Also see [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)